# tab javascript keeps hiding all tabs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried this javascript (taken from W3 schools) to create tabbed sections on my webpage.

Initially , it successfully shows the tab selected and hides the others.

Problem is, after a second or so, it seems to iterate again through all the tabs and hide the all the tabcontent unless it is marked active by default.

It does not seem to make a difference whether i mark the tabcontent "display:block" or not, except that when I do, it defaults to the first tab; when I don't, it hides all of them.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openSection(event, 'Inspection_Info')">Inspection Info</button>
  
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openSection(event, 'issue_list')">Issues</button>
  
  <div style="float:right;padding-top:8px;padding-right:5px;"><input class="push_button" id="top-save" name="commit" type="submit" value="Save"></div>
</div>

<div id="Inspection_Info" class="tabcontent" style="display:block;">
  inspection_info contents


</div>
<div class="tabcontent" id="issue_list" style="display:block;">
       issue_list contents
      
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* Style the tab */
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

/* Style the buttons that are used to open the tab content */
.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-family:inherit;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 0px;
  border: none;
}
```

Javascript:

```
function openSection(evt, sectionName) {
  // Declare all variables
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

  // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    if (tabcontent[i].id === sectionName) 
      {tabcontent[i].style.display = "block";}
    else
    {tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";}
  }

  // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }

  // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
  document.getElementById(sectionName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

Comment: I did not quite understand the problem. Can you explain it a bit further

Comment: is that your actual code or just a typo on the first line of your css (missing the leading slash for your comment)?  When I put your code (without the typo) into [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/5ra8d02p/) initially doesn't show any tab selected and shows the content of both tabs

Comment: that was a typo, as was the fact that I left both div's as "display:block", rather than only the first.  Here is the [corrected version](https://jsfiddle.net/afkuoy6x/). In my app (Ruby on Rails, fwiw), it always jumps back to mark all tabs as inactive. In this case, it would show Inspection Info by default."